# Reload javascript after thymeleaf fragment render

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have javascript files defined in the `<head>` of both my layout decorator template and my individual pages which are decorated. When I update a thymeleaf fragment in one of my pages the javascript defined in the head of the parent page no longer works. Is there a standard way to 'refresh' these js files?

Thanks.

Additional clarification :

I have a form submitted by an ajax call which updates a table in the page. I have a Jquery onClick function targeting a button in the updated table. The javascript doesn't seem able to bind to the returned elements in the updated part of the page. I select by element class and can see that the selection works prior to the partial fragment render.

Comment: Do you have $( document ).ready(function() in your JS?  Assuming it is JQuery.  Without code it is hard to tell what is happening.

Comment: I do have $( document ).ready(function() in my JS.

Comment: Is this happening during development or deployment?

Comment: Both environments are affected

Comment: Without code it is really hard to say.

Comment: please see my clarification in the original question, should make more sense now

Comment: @SionGriffiths did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me it is unclear what you mean by

> javascript defined in the head of the parent page no longer works.

The page is created on the server. Normally it contains urls of the  javascript files

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this case 'refreshing' the javascript files can happen only in the client.

Check the html of the page in the client.
Are the  tags as expected ?
Are there tags for all expected javascript files ?

With the browser tools (for example Google Chrom developer tools ) check that all script files are actually loaded.

If this doesnt help, it could be that the order of the script tags has changed between the first and second load. This could cause a different behaviour of the javascript executed in the browser.

**EDIT :**

With the initial load you bind javascript callbacks to dom elements.

You do this directly or through Jquery or other libraries.

When a new dom element is loaded, it has no callbacks bound to it, even if it has the same id as a replaced dom element.

So after the load you have to bind your callbacks again.

If you bound them 'by hand', just bind it again.

If you are using a JQuery plugin, that made the bindings, look into the code or documentation, many of them have a function for that or you can call initialization again.

Comment: I have a form submitted by an ajax call which updates a table in the page. I have a Jquery onClick function targeting a button in the updated table. The javascript doesn't seem able to bind to the returned elements in the updated part of the page.  I select by element class and can see that the selection works prior to the partial fragment render.

Comment: You need to "re-bind" the events after the loading. Something like $("#controls").off("click"); $("#controls").on("click", function() { });

Answer (score 0):

Once you added new content to the DOM you need to bind again the new content.

Let's say I have a button with some class, the event in binded to the class:

```
<button class="someclass">Button 1</button>

<script>
    var something = function() {
        // do something
    };
    $(".someclass").on("click", something);
</script>
```

If I add more buttons from the same class to the DOM, they will have not have the click event binded. So once you load the new content via ajax, also remove all binding and add again (you need to remove or you will have buttons with 2 events).

```
    $(".someclass").off("click");
    $(".someclass").on("click" , something);
```